# Facebook Open Authentication using Node JS and Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cors, passport-facebook

I am new to node and angular programming. I am trying out open authentication using node and angular js. The browser console throws the following error -

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%…%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&client_id=. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.**

I have used passport-facebook and passport module for open authentication.

Below is the code:

server.js

```
var auth = require('./app/routes/auth');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
app.use('/auth', auth);
```

app/routes/auth.js

```
var express = require('express'),
  passport = require('passport'),  
  router = express.Router(),
  mongoDB = require('mongoDB').MongoClient,
  GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

require('../configs/passport')(passport, mongoDB);

router.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/user/loginFailure'
  })
);

router.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

    // handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
router.get('/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook',
    {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/'
      }
));

router.get('/loginFailure', function(req, res){
  res.send("Login Failed..");
});

module.exports = router;


var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var fbConfig = require("./facebook.json");

module.exports = function(passport){

   passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({       
        clientID        : fbConfig.appID,
        clientSecret    : fbConfig.appSecret,
        callbackURL     : fbConfig.callbackURL

    },    
    function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {        
        process.nextTick(function() {            
                    var newUser = {};
                    newUser.facebook.id    = profile.id;
                    newUser.facebook.token = token; 
                    newUser.facebook.name  = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                    newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value; 
                        return done(null, newUser);

            });
    }));
};
```

angular controller. handles click event for Facebook login button.

```
app.controller("authCtrl",["$scope", '$resource', function($scope, $resource){
    $scope.userid = "";
    $scope.password = "";

    $scope.authenticate = function(type){
        if(type === 'local'){
            var login = $resource('http://localhost:3000/auth/login');
            login.save({username: $scope.userid, password: $scope.password });
        }        
        else if(type === 'facebook'){
            var login = $resource('http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook');
            login.get();
        }         
    }
}])
```

Please help in fixing this error.

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook auth strategy requires that the user be signed into Facebook and has allowed your "app" permission to access your Facebook account information. This cannot be done with an XHR because how would the user enter their Facebook credentials to log into Facebook if the user wasn't already signed in? How would the user approve the permissions your Facebook "app" is requesting if the request is sent via XHR?

This applies to all of the Passport strategies that utilize OAuth or OpenID. **The user's browser has to go directly to the auth provider's site** so that they can either A) login to the auth provider or B) approve the permissions you're requesting in your application. Once the user has done that the auth provider (in your case Facebook) will then redirect the user's browser back to your application's endpoint with some kind of token which your application will then use to request information from the auth provider (such as email address, full name, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your application with Facebook as a valid client? If so please make sure your redirect uri is registered as a valid redirect uri with FB.

Comment: yes i have registered the application. The appID, appSecret and the redirect url in Valid OAuth redirect URIs field of Advanced tab. This is how its done right?

Comment: Yes. Please refer to this link for details [link](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/facebook). Please ignore the Auth0 part of the section in the link provided. The error you are receiving is related to Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS for short), which shouldn't happen if you register the application with FB.

Comment: yes. This is exactly how i have done. And if i click on the URL from the error - https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%…%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&client_id=clientID. It gave me the authentication consent page and sucessfully logged me in.

Comment: k. Then this is clearly a CORS issue. CORS is enforced by browsers, so if you do the same request from Postman it works fine. Please refer to this article on how to deal with CORS [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). Hope this helps.

Comment: is this an issue with angular or node ?

Comment: It is on the angular side, since that code executes in Browser.